# New Bahia Yard is Extremely Lumpy

Tags: grass, yard

First-time home owner here.

It's been two months since they laid new bahia sod (suburb of Tampa, FL).
They laid it in late July, it's now early Oct.

- It is extremely bumpy/clumpy/lumpy.  I water it as they suggested (3 times/wk for approx 20 min early morning, then after a month or so, back off to twice/wk).
- It's so lumpy it feels like a safety hazard to even walk in the backyard (ankle breaker).
- The builder said it should even-out over time, but it feels like that would take a miracle.  Will it even out over time?
- I know these pictures can’t portray what I’m saying.

Anyone have experience with bahia lumpiness?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also, pest control happens every month and lawn treatment happens every other month - but as I said, it's only been two months.

Comment: I think @Bamboo 's answer on this question would apply to your situation.  https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22798/how-to-know-how-much-weight-i-need-in-a-lawn-roller

Comment: Thanks @MackM.
I don't understand why a newly laid yard shouldn't be close to perfect.
Maybe newly laid bahia is supposed to be clumpy for months, not sure.  I'm just looking for piece of mind that the sod layers weren't sloppy.  If it is normal, then I can deal with that (while hoping it levels out over time).

Answer (score 0):

A Lumpy yard due to sod, probably means whoever laid it out did a poor job of [preparing underlying soil](https://www.milorganite.com/blog/Lawn/how-improve-lumpy-lawn). When laying sod, the main goal is breaking up the soil beneath it and having it as flat as possible (or at [grade](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/lawns/reviews/yard-grading) to facilitate needed drainage needs) Preparing soil also allows the sod to grow a [deep](https://www.getsunday.com/shed/lawn/soil/why-root-depth-matters) taproot. The deeper the root, the more water and food storage to survive drought/winter and less periodic watering and maintenance.
Clay soils need to be broken up, and have addition of sand for adequate drainage.
Sandy soils, need more organic humic materials for water absorption.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  However, they did level it out before they laid the sod.  That stage is part of their process.

Comment: Did they grade it. That's why golf courses have so many sloping hills. To prevent sediment build and puddling

Comment: They did grade it